# Parsing poorl structured HTML document with Ruby Mechanize

Tags: html, ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize

I have a to parse a poorly structured HTML document with Ruby mechanize. There 2 forms in the page but there are few submit type buttons that does not comes under any form element, therefor i have not been able to click on those buttons.

There are two dropdowns and both are in different s and there submit button is outside these forms, i have to select the values from these DDs and click this button, i have not been able to click this button.

Any help??

All answers are appreciated...
Here is the sample HTML

```
<form action='abc/abc.asp'>
<select name='state'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
</form>

<select name='options'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Results">
```

Look, the second dropdown and button are outside any form, i want to select the value from  second DDL and hit the "View Results" button

Comment: Could you add some examples of the html?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this which should be the same result as clicking the button:

```
form['submit'] = 'View Results'
form.submit
```

Comment: No, there is not any button inside form, the button is in the page outside the form element.

Comment: @Nadeem, it doesn't matter. This will emulate a browser 'forgiving' the button for being outside the form.

Comment: i have tried it but got a 404 error, however if i clicked the same button using browser then there is no 404